# How can I set up routes in rails 2 so that it takes the string after root as a parameter to pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to set up my route as follows:

```
   subdomain.mydomain.com/VAR
```

I want VAR to be a variable that gets passed IF subdomain exists as a value in a record.  In other words, the controller for that show action would be able to grab params[:id] as the value "VAR"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you need exactly. But from what it appears you are trying to obtain a record based on the subdomain and based on the record found you want to further process the value passed as VAR.

A simple route would be something like:

```
map.posts_with_slug    "/:slug", :controller => "posts", :action => "show"
```

Handling of subdomain needs to be done separately:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :ensure_domain

  APP_DOMAIN = 'myapp.mydomain.com'

  def ensure_domain
    if request.env['HTTP_HOST'] != APP_DOMAIN
      # HTTP 301 is a "permanent" redirect
      redirect_to "http://#{APP_DOMAIN}", :status => 301
    end
  end
end
```

Source code example used from Heroku Docs for handling custom domains.

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Hope this helps.